# How to model continuous predictor variable, $x\ge0$, showing continuity "jump" at $x=0$?

Tags: logistic, zero-inflation

I'm modeling hospital inpatient stays with a logistic regression model, and have encountered a number of predictor variables measuring # of outpatient care episodes which have an inflated number of observations at $x=0$ (sometimes over 90%). In addition, there's a discontinuous "jump" in observed y values comparing $x=0$ with $x>0$.

Plotting a decile chart with $x=0$ to $10$ and looking at the proportion of people with inpatient stays within each decile reveals the following pattern as a typical example:

[image]

One solution I'm tinkering with is to describe x with two component variables,

- a binary variable $x_1$ where $x_1=0$ if $x=0$, $x_1=1$ if $x>0$, and
- a continuous variable $x_2=x$.

Then describe the model equation as:

$\text{logit}(y)=\beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2x_2)x_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_1x_2$

`If x1=0 then logit(y) = beta0. Else if x1=1 then logit(y) = (beta0 + beta1) + beta2*x2`.

However I'm unsure if this is a standard procedure for modeling predictor variables that exhibit this behavior?

Comment: This approach is standard but it also seems pointless, because it's tantamount to putting a single observation into its own group and separately fitting it.  You might just as well remove the first observation and fit the rest of the data.  Note, too, that p-values, predictions, etc. will be problematic due to the interaction between model specification and model fitting that is going on here.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for confirming this approach. Yes, I agree about removing the x=0 observations if I were modeling only y and x in the logistic regression. However, my dataset has several dozen of these "zero-inflated" predictors interspersed among the patients. Removing the x=0 obs would mean deleting a big section of my dataset. I'm using a lasso for variable selection/coeff determination, so p-values aren't an issue.

Comment: Argh, of course I'm seeing multicollinearity issues using the above choice of variables. I'll have to chalk this up as an unresolved issue until I find a solution.